# Coupled inductors formula

Tags: current, transformer, analog, inductor, coupling

Suppose we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Yo8E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to the dot notation rule the current :The convention is that current entering a transformer at the end of a winding marked with a dot, will tend to produce current exiting other windings at their dotted ends.

If the windings werent coupled to each other we would have these 2 equations for currents:

I1 = If1(1-e^(-R1t/L1))  = VCC/R1(1-e^(-R1t/L1))

I2 = If2(1-e^(-R2t/L2))  = VCC/R2(1-e^(-R2t/L2))

but now there are coupled and there is a term M(dI2/dt).Which is the equation of current for that term?

Comment: Current isn't generated by mutual inductance. Mutual inductance creates induction and that is a voltage phenomena. Current is produced when the induced voltage (in a second winding) is connected to a circuit that allows current to flow.

Comment: I say this because the response of an inductor in a varying current through it , the inductor becomes a current source for some time.